# How to make a Scaffold TopAppBar to wrap content height of its childrens?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I tried with `Modifier.wrapContentHeight()` but it doesn't work.

Seems that `ToppAppBar` has a fixed height and does not wrap the height of his childrens.

How can that be achieved?

The sample code:

```
 Scaffold(
        modifier = modifier,
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                modifier = Modifier.wrapContentHeight(),
                title = {
                    Row(
                        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(8.dp)
                    ) {
                        Image(
                            painterResource(id = R.drawable.foreground),
                            contentDescription = null,
                            modifier = Modifier.size(72.dp),
                            contentScale = ContentScale.Fit
                        )
                        Text(
                            stringResource(id = R.string.app_name),
                            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                            style = MaterialTheme.typography.headlineLarge
                        )
                    }
                }
            )
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the `TopAppBar` internally uses `AppBar` component that has fixed height of `56.dp` and you won't be able to override it as its private component. Hence, there is only option for you to achieve your requirement i.e., create custom `TopAppBar`

You can use below `TopAppBar` instead of `material` one:

```
private val AppBarHorizontalPadding = 4.dp
private val TitleInsetWithoutIcon = Modifier.width(16.dp - AppBarHorizontalPadding)
private val TitleIconModifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight()
    .width(72.dp - AppBarHorizontalPadding)

@Composable
fun TopAppBar(
    title: @Composable () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    navigationIcon: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
    actions: @Composable RowScope.() -> Unit = {},
    backgroundColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.primarySurface,
    contentColor: Color = contentColorFor(backgroundColor),
    elevation: Dp = AppBarDefaults.TopAppBarElevation
) {
    AppBar(
        backgroundColor,
        contentColor,
        elevation,
        AppBarDefaults.ContentPadding,
        RectangleShape,
        modifier
    ) {
        if (navigationIcon == null) {
            Spacer(TitleInsetWithoutIcon)
        } else {
            Row(TitleIconModifier, verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
                CompositionLocalProvider(
                    LocalContentAlpha provides ContentAlpha.high,
                    content = navigationIcon
                )
            }
        }

        Row(
            Modifier.wrapContentHeight().weight(1f),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            ProvideTextStyle(value = MaterialTheme.typography.h6) {
                CompositionLocalProvider(
                    LocalContentAlpha provides ContentAlpha.high,
                    content = title
                )
            }
        }

        CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentAlpha provides ContentAlpha.medium) {
            Row(
                Modifier.wrapContentHeight(),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.End,
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                content = actions
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun TopAppBar(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    backgroundColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.primarySurface,
    contentColor: Color = contentColorFor(backgroundColor),
    elevation: Dp = AppBarDefaults.TopAppBarElevation,
    contentPadding: PaddingValues = AppBarDefaults.ContentPadding,
    content: @Composable RowScope.() -> Unit
) {
    AppBar(
        backgroundColor,
        contentColor,
        elevation,
        contentPadding,
        RectangleShape,
        modifier = modifier,
        content = content
    )
}

@Composable
private fun AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Color,
    contentColor: Color,
    elevation: Dp,
    contentPadding: PaddingValues,
    shape: Shape,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    content: @Composable RowScope.() -> Unit
) {
    Surface(
        color = backgroundColor,
        contentColor = contentColor,
        elevation = elevation,
        shape = shape,
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentAlpha provides ContentAlpha.medium) {
            Row(
                Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(contentPadding)
                    .wrapContentHeight(),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Start,
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                content = content
            )
        }
    }
}
```