How to disable TopAppBar's navigationIcon and actions hidden paddings?

Does anyone know how to remove paddings from navigationIcon and actions from TopAppBar? There are no paddings in the code, they come from who knows where. Yellow - TopAppBar, red - navigationIcon and actions. Tried windowInsets 0.dp for all for TopAppBar, doesn't work. I'm talking about paddings between Yellow and Red.
@Composable
fun RootScaffold(
    content: @Composable () -> Unit,
    screenTitle: String,
    topBarMenuChar: Char,
    floatingActionButton: @Composable () -> Unit? = {}
) {
    val drawerState = rememberDrawerState(initialValue = DrawerValue.Closed)
    ModalNavigationDrawer(
        drawerState = drawerState,
        drawerContent = {
            ModalDrawerSheet { /* Drawer content */ }
        },
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(Color.Black)
                .paint(
                    painterResource(R.drawable.bg_app),
                    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                    alpha = 0.12F
                )
                .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondary.copy(alpha = 0.12F))
                .padding(horizontal = 20.dp)
        ) {
            Scaffold(
                containerColor = Color.Transparent,
                topBar = { RootTopAppBar(screenTitle, topBarMenuChar) },
                floatingActionButton = { floatingActionButton() }
            ) { paddingValues ->
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(paddingValues)
                ) {
                    content()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
 
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun RootTopAppBar(title: String, menuChar: Char) {
    val scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.pinnedScrollBehavior(rememberTopAppBarState())
 
    TopAppBar(
        colors = topAppBarColors(
            containerColor = Color.Yellow
        ),
        title = {
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 12.dp).background(Color.Blue),
                text = title
            )
        },
        navigationIcon = {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(31.dp)
                    .border(1.dp, MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary, CircleShape).background(Color.Red),
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "$menuChar",
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
                )
            }
        },
        actions = {
                Icon(
                    modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Red),
                    painter = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_plus),
                    contentDescription = "Localized description"
                )
        },
        scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior,
    )
}


You will have to create custom TopAppBar instead of using material app bar. Checkout this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78040651/19212377 ..... You just need to remove code block that sets navigationIcon content and action item content!

Hey , when we are using TopAppBar composable from Material3 API , if you look into inner code , you'll find one variable named TopAppBarHorizontalPadding , which is used while building NavigationIcon & actionIcon and that variable is predefined & private . This is answer to your question , from where these padding come , as you haven't defined it in your code . As i'm new to compose , don't know about how to override that value .

TopAppBar uses private val AppBarHorizontalPadding = 4.dp, it's a const that cannot be changed. Two solutions:
If you don't have any horizontal paddings for your TopAppBar, then you should create a custom TopAppBar
If you have any horizontal paddings for TopAppBar, just make them 4.dp less.
